# 3D mesh edge detection / feature line computation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graphics, mesh

I have a program that visualizes triangular meshes and allows the users to draw on the meshes using a pen. I want to have a "snapping" mode in my system. The snapping mode performs drawing corrections for the user in the sense that the user-drawn lines are snapped to the nearest edge (or the silhouette) of that part of the mesh.

I'm looking for an algorithm that compute the edges visible on the mesh from a given point of view. By edges, I'm referring to the outlines of the shape: corner points and the lines between them (similar to the definition of an edge in computer vision/image processing -- such as Canny edges).

So far I've thought of two approaches for this:

1. Edge detection: so far I've only found [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=f3fd1d21ad3002444e7cab714f09c72a7ee02e82). Their method is understandable, yet the implementation is not trivial (due to tensor computations and some ambiguity in their explanations). The problem with this approach is that it produces "edge strength values" which is a value in the range [0, 1] for every vertex. The value of 1 indicates an edge vertex with a high confidence. This introduces extra thresholding parameters in the system which I'd rather not have. Their output looks like this (range [0, 1] scaled to [0, 65535]):
   [image]
2. Rendering or non-photorealistic methods such as the one asked in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68401/how-can-i-draw-outlines-around-3d-models) or [this paper](http://www.sci.utah.edu/%7Eroni/research/projects/NPR-lines/NPR-lines.NPAR09.pdf). They seem to be able to create the silhouette that I'm after as can be seen below:[image]
   I'm not a graphics expert and as of yet I don't know whether their methods can be used for computation of the feature lines rather than rendering.

I was wondering if anybody has any ideas about a good algorithm for what I want to do. Since the system is very interactive, the performance is important. The snapping feature does not have to be enabled all the time (therefore, if the method is computationally expensive, some delay in when "snapping enabled" mode is toggled can be tolerated while the algorithm is computing the edges.) Also, if you know of any implementation (preferably open source), I'd be grateful if you could share it with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since posting the question, something else came into my head. Since 2D edge detection is a very well-studied problem, one way of tackling the problem is performing 2D edge detection on the projection image of the mesh.

In other words, given a specific view of the mesh, one could generate a 2D image. A 2D edge detection algorithm (such as Canny edge detector) could then be run on the 2D image and the results can be back-projected to 3D to determine the silhouettes of the mesh in question. One possible advantage of this is simplicity!

**Edit (2017):**

Even though I moved away from this, I returned to this problem again for a different purpose. To anybody else looking into this problem: [there is a paper](http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/DeCarlo_2003_SCF/DeCarlo2003.pdf) that talks about various contours from meshes that's worth reading *(the paper is "Suggestive Contours for Conveying Shape" by DeCarlo et al.).*

Working implementation of the methods discussed in the paper are [available here](https://github.com/garyzhao/Sketch3DToolkit).

Comment: There's already an implementation of this in PCL. Read more about it here http://www.pointclouds.org/blog/gsoc12/cchoi/index.php

Comment: @PavanK This was a Google Summer of Code assignment. I cannot find the original link anymore, but the project was called "3D edge extraction from an organized point cloud
" (more details https://www.google-melange.com/archive/gsoc/2012/orgs/pcl/projects/cchoi.html)

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of edges that you want to detect:

- silhouette edges are viewpoint dependent, they correspond to the places where the line of sight tangents the surfaces. With a triangulated model, they are easy to determine, as they are shared by a front-facing triangle and a back-facing one.
- "angular" edges are viewpoint independent and formed by a discontinuity in the tangent plane direction. As a triangulated model has itself this kind of discontinuity, there is no exact criterion to find them. Just set a threshold on the angle formed by two triangles. This threshold must be such that smooth patches do not trigger.

By this approach, you will find the wanted edges in 3D.

This is not enough, as part of them are hidden by other surfaces. You have the option of integrating them as edges in the 3D model and letting the rendering engine do its job, or, if you have the courage, to implement an [hidden lines removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_line_removal) algorithm. (The wikipedia link is a little terse.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The first method you mentioned seems more appropriate for my case (because the user will draw with a pen from a single point of view, and will then rotate/translate the model and draw from a different point of view). How's the computation exactly? For every triangle, if there is an adjacent back facing triangle, we can assume that one of the edges is "the" edge we are looking for?

Comment: @M2X: maybe I didn't explain clearly enough. You don't have the option of choosing one kind of another, you need to handle both (unless your objects have no salient edge).

Comment: @M2X: you can consider every edge in turn, knowing the two triangles it belongs to. This information is normally available while you are meshing. If it has been lost, you need to reconstruct it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust , is there any paper you can suggest for "angular" edges?

Comment: @YvesDaoust i think your insight is right, i am working on an angular version atm, but i cant find something similar published.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - Can you please elaborate on the 2nd (angular) part? I'm working on something similar and it's a bit urgent.

Comment: As in, what should I do when suppose two triangles are found to be making an angle larger than a threshold? How do I extract a curve from those 2 triangles?

Comment: @Ketan: keep the common edge.

Comment: Even though I moved away from this, I returned to this problem again for a different purpose. To anybody else looking into this problem: [there is a paper](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~decarlo/pubs/sg03.pdf) that talks about various contours from meshes that's worth reading. Working implementation of the methods discussed in the paper are [available here](https://github.com/garyzhao/Sketch3DToolkit).